# How can I check if a variable is set and is the same value as another one which comes from a loop?

Tags: php, get

The thing is that I want to check if user's super variable is same as a value that I have on another variable that contains an array of values.

The problem is that the array is on 2 dimentions, so I need to loop the array before checking if it matches with the variable I am getting from the URL.

I don't want to do it with a function, but the best way of accomplishing it.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$detalles = [
             array("nombre"=>"Manzana", "precio"=>45.95, "color"=>"Rojo"),
             array("nombre"=>"Pera", "precio"=>40.36, "color"=>"Verde"),
             array("nombre"=>"Uva", "precio"=>95.21, "color"=>"Purpura"),
             array("nombre"=>"Naranja", "precio"=>15.60, "color"=>"Naranja"),
             array("nombre"=>"Mango", "precio"=>10.80, "color"=>"Amarillo")
             ];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Results of $_GET variable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin-top: 20px" class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Product details</td>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($detalles as $producto): 
            
                    if(!isset($_GET['producto']) || $producto["nombre"] != $_GET['producto']){
                        header('Location: index.php');
                    }
                    if($producto["nombre"] == $_GET['producto']): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre:</td>
                <td>{ <?php echo $producto["nombre"]; ?> }</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Precio:</td>
                <td>{ <?php echo $producto["precio"]; ?> }</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Color:</td>
                <td>{ <?php echo $producto["color"]; ?> }</td>
            </tr>
            <?php endif;
                    break;
                endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the details.php file, there's a file that is previous of this one which has a form with a get method and an action so everything works fine, my logic is what is not right.

Thank you in advance.
Blessings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You check in every loop if `$_GET['producto']` is set. You have to check it once before the loop.
- Don't print the details in your loop. First you have to find the product, and *then* show the details.

```php
<?php
if( !isset($_GET['producto']) ) header("Location: index.php");

$found = null;

foreach($detalles as $producto){
    if( $producto["nombre"] == $_GET['producto']){
        $found = $producto;
        break;
    }
}
?>

<tr>
    <td>Nombre:</td>
    <td>{ <?php echo $found["nombre"]; ?> }</td>
</tr>
...
```

Comment: Thanks to your code I could improve mine, thank you again.
What do you suggest me to do so I could improve my coding logic and get better as a developer?